# Using only CSS & HTML, how can I set a div with a padding of 20% to change to 0% if the window is reduced to a specific size?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have several divs with the CSS

```html
.bodyText {
margin:auto;
padding: 1% 20%; 
}
```

But when the screen gets reduced to the size of, say, an iPhone screen I want to reduce the left & right padding to 1%.
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). That should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). These are denoted by the `@` symbol in CSS, and can not only target screen widths, but also specific orienations:

```
/* Any iPhone */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   .bodyText {
        padding: 1%;
    }
} 

/* iPhone Portrait */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {
   .bodyText {
        padding: 1%;
    }
} 

/* iPhone Landscape */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:landscape) {
   .bodyText {
        padding: 1%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). There are rules for set specific size of screen, or more.
Example:

```
@media (max-size: 800px) {
   // here is your code
}
```